# Is it possible to have an infinite horizontal paging uiscrollview for page control in swift 4?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Say I have an array of strings and every time I swipe, I want the text on the screen to be a random string from the array without reaching an end. How would I do that?

Comment: Well, actually you can create an infinite scroll with `UIScrollView`. Need some tricks though. It is like a implementing custom UITableView but need to set contentOffset to center of the contentSize without animation and simulate the animation the scrollView had.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have an infinite scroll view. A UIScrollView is a view onto a rectangular area. That rectangular area can be large, but it has limits.

A `UIPageViewController` might do what you want. It's been a while since I used one, but looking at the docs it looks like you can either provide an array of view controllers or provide a `dataSource` that conforms to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. It sounds like you could use a `dataSource` to serve up an infinite set of view controllers containing your strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `UIPageViewController`.

Here is a simple example (add a `UIPageViewController` to your storyboard, and set its Class to `InfinitePageViewController`):

```
//
//  InfinitePageViewController.swift
//  InfinitePages
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/30/18.
//

import UIKit

// simple random color extension
extension UIColor {
    static func randomColor(saturation: CGFloat = 1, brightness: CGFloat = 1, alpha: CGFloat = 1) -> UIColor {
        let hue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(361)) / 360.0
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
    }
}

class SinglePageViewController: UIViewController {

    var theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()

        view.addSubview(theLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            ])

    }

}

class InfinitePageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var stringArray = [
        "1 - Do not consider painful what is good for you.",
        "2 - It is better to look ahead and prepare than to look back and regret.",
        "3 - The easiest thing in the world to be is you. The most difficult thing to be is what other people want you to be. Don't let them put you in that position.",
        "4 - A book is a version of the world. If you do not like it, ignore it; or offer your own version in return.",
        "5 - The scientific name for an animal that doesn't either run from or fight its enemies is lunch.",
        "6 - To love is to receive a glimpse of heaven.",
        "7 - Patriotism is your conviction that this country is superior to all other countries because you were born in it.",
        "8 - There is but one temple in the universe and that is the body of man.",
        "9 - It is easier to get forgiveness than permission.",
        "10 - There is always more misery among the lower classes than there is humanity in the higher.",
        "11 - Success is counted sweetest by those who ne'er succeed.",
        "12 - Indifference and neglect often do much more damage than outright dislike.",
        "13 - For what do we live, but to make sport for our neighbours, and laugh at them in our turn?",
        "14 - Last night somebody broke into my apartment and replaced everything with exact duplicates... When I pointed it out to my roommate, he said, 'Do I know you?'",
        "15 - Do not weep; do not wax indignant. Understand.",
        "16 - Work saves us from three great evils: boredom, vice and need.",
        "17 - You can discover what your enemy fears most by observing the means he uses to frighten you.",
        "18 - Rest satisfied with doing well, and leave others to talk of you as they please.",
        "19 - People want economy and they will pay any price to get it.",
        "20 - On the whole human beings want to be good, but not too good, and not quite all the time.",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self

        // create the first "page"
        let vc = SinglePageViewController()
        vc.theLabel.text = stringArray[0]

        // set it as the initial page VC
        self.setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // don't allow scrolling backward
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let vc = SinglePageViewController()
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(stringArray.count)))
        vc.theLabel.text = stringArray[randomIndex]
        return vc
    }

}
```

This will scroll infinitely, picking a random string from `stringArray` for each new page.

Because this is simply getting a random string from the array, it's entirely possible that you will get the same string multiple times - even sequentially. If you don't want that, one approach is to shuffle an array of index numbers, and then step through that array. When you've reached the end, shuffle the numbers again and continue on.

Comment: Nice. I wrote a quick page view controller demo app and tried to push it to GitHub from work but our office security is blocking me for some reason.

Comment: One minor point: If you shuffler your array, go to the end, then shuffle it again, you can still get a repeat item if the last entry from one shuffle is the same as the first entry from the new shuffle. I created a class "RandomItems" that serves up random items from an array and avoids that case.

Comment: True... shuffling at the end certainly could result in a repeat item... and you'd want to handle that case. Of course, the OP asked for "infinite random display of strings from a finite array" - so, with only that instruction, it would be *valid* to show the same string 5 times in a row. Almost certainly not what he had in mind though :)

Comment: My project RandomObjects on Github addresses the "repeats at the end" problem: https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomObjects